# Can not load reprojected shapefile - GDAL Python ERROR 4

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I've created a function based on the code snippet of the [gdal cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#reproject-a-layer) to reproject a shapefile to a new crs.
However if I try to load the reprojected shapefile I'll get `ERROR 4: 'SamplepointsEPSG_5678/Reprojected.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.`

What I've found so far - if I try to load the reprojected shapefile to QGIS no crs is set for it. When I set it there manually the location fits.

```
def reprojectShape(inputShape, EPSGout, outPathName):
  
  driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
  
  # input SpatialReference
  inLayer = inputShape.GetLayer()
  proj = inLayer.GetSpatialRef()
  EPSGin = int(proj.GetAttrValue('AUTHORITY',1))

  inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
  inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(EPSGin)
  
  # output SpatialReference
  outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
  outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(EPSGout)
  
  # create the CoordinateTransformation
  coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
  
  # get the input layer
  inLayer = inputShape.GetLayer()
  
  # create the output layer
  outLayerName = "Reprojected"
  if os.path.exists(outPathName):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outPathName)
  outDataSet = driver.CreateDataSource(outPathName)
  outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer(outLayerName, geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)
  
  # add fields
  inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
  for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)
  
  # get the output layer's feature definition
  outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
  
  # loop through the input features
  inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
  while inFeature:
      # get the input geometry
      geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
      # reproject the geometry
      geom.Transform(coordTrans)
      # create a new feature
      outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
      # set the geometry and attribute
      outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
      for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
          outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))
      # add the feature to the shapefile
      outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
      # dereference the features and get the next input feature
      outFeature = None
      inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
  
  # Save and close the shapefiles
  inDataSet = None
  outDataSet = None
  
  # return
  outName = os.path.join(outPathName,".".join([outLayerName,"shp"]))
  return(outName)

inName = os.path.splitext(Psamplepoints)[0]
outName = "".join([inName,"EPSG_",str(EPSGout)])
PreprojectedShape = reprojectShape(inputShape = input_samplepoints, EPSGout = targetEPSG, outPathName = outName)
input_samplepoints = gdal.Open(PreprojectedShape)
```

Comment: Any reason you are projecting the geometries one by one rather than just `gdal.VectorTranslate(outPathName, Psamplepoints, dstSRS="EPSG:{}".format(EPSGout), reproject=True)`?

Comment: Oh man I didn't know such a short function exists. It seems to fit perfectly for my case, thanks! Why are those things not in the gdal documentation?

Comment: https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslate

Comment: The  GDAL/OGR Cookbook isn't official GDAL documentation and is quite out of date in some respects. There doesn't seem to be any examples of the [GDAL utilities as library](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library.html) functions, such as `gdal.VectorTranslate` which were released with GDAL 2.1 in 2016.

Comment: Okay but is there any useful gdal documentations for python/gdal newbies? The official documentation is wayy to cryptic for me, the cookbook ist old and the gdal website provides mainly C/C++ content. Or am I just to fastidious learning R first with it's great documentation infrastructure. At least the stackexchange community is a lifesaver for me :) Thanks.

Comment: GDAL documentation is pretty ordinary I agree. There's some libraries built on top of GDAL that are much better documented and easier to use, such as rasterio, fiona, geopandas.